# Error: [CKEDITOR.dialog.openDialog] Dialog Image failed when loading definition in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

**Only in production**, when i try to insert image in CKEditor i get the Error:

> [CKEDITOR.dialog.openDialog] Dialog Image failed when loading definition

and when i try to add tables i get:

> [CKEDITOR.dialog.openDialog] Dialog table failed when loading definition.

The other options of editor work correctly and the version in bower.json is: `"ckeditor": "#full/4.5.4",`

My toolbar configuration is:

```
    $ckEditorProvider.setDefaults({
          toolbar: [
            {
              name: 'editing',
              items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt', '-']
            },
            {
              name: 'insert',
              items: ['Image','Table']
            },
            '/',
            {
              name: 'styles',
              items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']
            }
          ]
        });

    CKEDITOR.basePath = location.href.substr(0, location.href.indexOf(location.hash)) + 'bower_components/ckeditor/';
    CKEDITOR.plugins.basePath = location.href.substr(0, location.href.indexOf(location.hash)) + 'bower_components/ckeditor/plugins';
}
```

Does anyone have a clue why this happens?